# JDBC shows syntax error but the query runs just fine in HeidiSQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, kotlin

I'm using jasync for ktor to connect to mysql. All my queries run fine except this one query. It shows a syntax error even after remove parts of the query.

Mysql is running and processes queries just fine. I run the same query in HeidiSQL and it returns just fine, no errors.

```
USE ${city.getString("DbName")};

SELECT
    m.id AS meter_id,
    m.meter_num AS meter_number,
    IF(
        l.split = 0,
        m.route_id,
        CONCAT(
            CAST(m.route_id AS CHAR),
            CAST(l.split AS CHAR)
        )
    ) AS route_id,
    m.sequence AS sequence_number,
    m.address,
    m.location,
    m.location_2,
    m.location_3,
    m.previous_read,
    m.account_num AS account_number,
    m.low_limit,
    m.high_limit,
    m.low_usage,
    m.high_usage,
    m.calc_usage AS calculated_usage,
    m.num_dials,
    CONCAT(h.Date, h.Time, LPAD(h.time_seconds, 2, '0')) as date_time,
    c.utility,
    c.acct_owner AS account_owner,
    c.MeterCode AS meter_code,
    m.msg,
    c.misc1,
    c.misc2,
    c.misc3,
    c.active,
    c.backward,
    mcd.always_require_photo AS require_photo
FROM
    datazeo.meters AS m
    INNER JOIN datazeo.routes AS rt ON rt.id = m.route_id
    INNER JOIN info.loads AS l ON l.RouteID = rt.route
    INNER JOIN custfile AS c ON c.IDnum = m.meter_num
    LEFT JOIN acsreads AS r ON r.IDnum = c.IDnum
    LEFT JOIN history AS h ON
        h.IDnum = c.IDnum
        AND h.Month = $month
    LEFT JOIN datazeo.meter_customer_data AS mcd ON mcd.meter_id = m.id
WHERE
    m.city_id = $cityId
    AND rt.city_id = $cityId
    AND l.CityID = "$paddedCityId"
    AND l.ReaderID = ${requestContext.user.id}
    AND r.IDnum IS NULL
    AND l.Recheck = 0
    AND (
        l.split = 0
        OR (
            m.sequence >= l.seq_start
            AND m.sequence <= l.seq_end
        )
)
```

The query returns 27 columns and 153 rows when using HeidiSQL.
But i get this error when running it in kotlin with jasync and JDBC...

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT
m.id AS meter_id,
m.meter_num AS meter_number,
IF(
    l.' at line 3"
```

Comment: @Zendie Edit rejected. You made it worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. For whatever reason JDBC doesnt allow you to send a USE statement in the same request as your select.

So I replaces my code to look like this

```sql
SELECT
    m.id AS meter_id,
    m.meter_num AS meter_number,
    IF(
        l.split = 0,
        m.route_id,
        CONCAT(
            CAST(m.route_id AS CHAR),
            CAST(l.split AS CHAR)
        )
    ) AS route_id,
    m.sequence AS sequence_number,
    m.address,
    m.location,
    m.location_2,
    m.location_3,
    m.previous_read,
    m.account_num AS account_number,
    m.low_limit,
    m.high_limit,
    m.low_usage,
    m.high_usage,
    m.calc_usage AS calculated_usage,
    m.num_dials,
    CONCAT(h.Date, h.Time, LPAD(h.time_seconds, 2, '0')) as date_time,
    c.utility,
    c.acct_owner AS account_owner,
    c.MeterCode AS meter_code,
    m.msg,
    c.misc1,
    c.misc2,
    c.misc3,
    c.active,
    c.backward,
    mcd.always_require_photo AS require_photo
FROM
    datazeo.meters AS m
    INNER JOIN datazeo.routes AS rt ON rt.id = m.route_id
    INNER JOIN info.loads AS l ON l.RouteID = rt.route
    INNER JOIN ${city.getString("DbName")}.custfile AS c ON c.IDnum = m.meter_num
    LEFT JOIN ${city.getString("DbName")}.acsreads AS r ON r.IDnum = c.IDnum
    LEFT JOIN ${city.getString("DbName")}.history AS h ON
        h.IDnum = c.IDnum
        AND h.Month = $month
    LEFT JOIN datazeo.meter_customer_data AS mcd ON mcd.meter_id = m.id
WHERE
    m.city_id = $cityId
    AND rt.city_id = $cityId
    AND l.CityID = "$paddedCityId"
    AND l.ReaderID = ${requestContext.user.id}
    AND r.IDnum IS NULL
    AND l.Recheck = 0
    AND (
        l.split = 0
        OR (
            m.sequence >= l.seq_start
            AND m.sequence <= l.seq_end
        )
)
```

Just specify the database before the table and works fine now.

Comment: It doesn't allow multiple statements of any kind.